# Copy tables between databases in AS400

Tags: database, ibm-midrange

I have 2 DB2 databases (testing and production). In order to move tables between them, some users have a (probably coded by an admin) function called **ftpfile** from inside the emulator. I do not have access to the said emulator, my account has *INITIAL_MENU_NAME = '*SIGNOFF'* but I can connect from third party tools like *DBeaver*. Is there a way to move tables between environments?

Comment: how do you connect to the two databases?  From a terminal prompt can you run the FTP command and connect to each system?

Comment: @RockBoro through DBeaver, ftp to db name or ip is getting blocked

Comment: can you "select * from system1/table", get the column names of the selected rows, then "insert into system2/table ( col1, col2, col3 ) values( v1, v2, v3 )" on the target system?

Comment: Wouldn't that append the values to the target?

Comment: What connections are set up between the two servers? Is the target server in the database directory? Is APPC set up? Do you have a sign-on program that takes you to a menu? This is really a question for your admin. There are too many possibilities, and they all depend on the configuration of the systems.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I'll try to answer what I can in order. I think FTP, idk, yes, the emulator (black window) but my account is set to *SIGNOFF

Comment: Your account being set to SIGNOFF only means that when the initial program ends, your job ends, but you can still log in to an emulator, and in some cases may have command line privileges. The initial program is a part of your user profile which tells the OS to run that program when the job starts. When an initial program is present, the user profile is generally set to *SIGNOFF. Meaning SIGNOFF does not really affect what you can and cannot do.

Comment: What happens when you log in using the Emulator?

Comment: I get back to the logon screen.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem very unlikely for you to have the authority to "move tables".

You might be able to copy the data.

The easiest way would be something like so, while connected to the destination system.

```
delete from library.table
with nc;

insert into library.table
  select * from system2.library.table  
  with nc;
```

But being able to do that requires that the systems and your user profile be configured to allow it.

Really the right answer here is for you to contact your admin/security team and get the access required to do your job.

Comment: Upvoted, thank you for the effort, but it won't work since it requires a connection to both systems at the same time, through DBeaver, I can only connect to one at a time. And you're right but they won't allow it for developer to get access to production.

Comment: DBeaver would only be connected to a single system.   The server itself reaches out to the second system.  Thus the reason I mention that the systems must be configure to allow it.